# Getting the row of tableview

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

How can I get the `indexPath.row` when a button is tapped? Here is the code I have now:

```
let alert = SCLAlertView()
let txt = alert.addTextField("Quantity")
txt.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.NumberPad
txt.text = "\(1)"

alert.addButton("Add to cart") {
    var sar:Cart!
    let indexPath = self.tableView?.indexPathForSelectedRow
    print("\(indexPath.row)")
}
```

But it didn't work.

Comment: Which user's action is causing an alert view to appear?

Comment: It doesn't work because tapping a button doesn't select the row.

Comment: @pedrouan an IBAction

Comment: @rmaddy How can i select the row

Comment: Tapping a button won't select the row. To select a row you need to tap on the tableview cell and not any button.

Comment: You should fire an alert from within UITableView row, so implement a didSelectRow() delegate method.

Comment: You don't need to select the row. There are proper ways to get the index path based on the button.

Comment: @rmaddy Yes i dont want to select the row how can i do it?